# Makefile can't find input files in specified directory

Tags: shell, c

I am working with the following Makefile:

```
CFLAGS=-g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -rdynamic -DNDEBUG $(OPTFLAGS)
LIBS=-ldl $(OPTLIBS)
PREFIX?=/usr/local

SOURCES=$(wildcard src/lcthw/*.c src/*.c)
OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES))

TEST_SRC=$(wildcard tests/*_tests.c)
TESTS=$(patsubst %.c,%,$(TEST_SRC))

TARGET=build/libYOUR_LIBRARY.a
SO_TARGET=$(patsubst %.a,%.so,$(TARGET))

all: $(TARGET) $(SO_TARGET) tests

dev: CFLAGS=-g -Wall -Isrc -Wall -Wextra $(OPTFLAGS)
dev: all

$(TARGET): CFLAGS += -fPIC
$(TARGET): build $(OBJECTS)
   ar rcs $@ $(OBJECTS)
   ranlib $@

$(SO_TARGET): $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
   $(CC) -shared -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

build:
   @mkdir -p build
   @mkdir -p bin

# The Unit Tests
.PHONY: tests
tests: CFLAGS += $(TARGET)
tests: $(TESTS)
   sh ./tests/runtests.sh

valgrind:
   VALGRIND="valgrind --log-file=/tmp/valgrind-%p.log" $(MAKE)

# The Cleaner
clean:
   rm -rf build $(OBJECTS) $(TESTS)
   rm -f tests/tests.log
   find . -name "*.gc*" -exec rm {} \;
   rm -rf `find . -name "*.dSYM" -print`

install: all
   install -d $(DESTDIR)/$(PREFIX)/lib/
   install $(TARGET) $(DESTDIR)/$(PREFIX)/lib/
```

And I'm having trouble with this line:

```
$(CC)   -shared -o  $@  $(OBJECTS)
```

I am getting the error:

```
cc: fatal error: no input files
```

when I try and run any of the following commands: make, make all and make dev. Why can't my makefile find the .c files in the directories I specified?

Comment: Is this a program you're working on (as a programmer) as opposed to something you're trying to install (as a sysadmin)? If the former, the folks on [so] are probably much more knowledgeable about the details of writing makefiles. If you want the question moved, please flag it, select in need of moderator intervention, and ask for it to be moved to Stack Overflow. Or leave a comment that it should be moved, and the community can do it. (I don't think you can flag your own question as off-topic, move to SO, but that'd work too).

Comment: Also, just to check the obvious: you have done an `src/lcthw/*.c src/*.c` just to make sure there are files there, right?

Comment: Its a program I'm working on so thanks for the suggestion I'll move it to stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the full paths in this line:

SOURCES=$(wildcard src/lcthw/*.c src/*.c)

OTW this becomes a constraint on where you can run the make command from. Possibly what's happening is that the wildcards are not being expanded since the directory you are sitting in, `$(CURDIR)` , makes it hard for it to see these paths.

You should try printing these variables from inside your makefile, by doing:

```
$(info source=$(SOURCES))
```

And if your .obj files are placed in a different location than the sources, then you need to account for that by including that place in the $(OBJECTS) as well.